# How do I pass a variable struct type to a function in C

Tags: c, function, variables, struct, arguments

I want to create a fire and forget function for handling the memory space held by all the elements of a linked list.It takes three parameters, a pointer to a struct(which I want to be of variable type)which acts as the list head,a pointer to no of elements in this struct,and a boolean flag specifying whether or not to free memory held by all elements or just the one in which 'alive' is false.If this flag is not specified,only the elements whose alive field is set to false are removed.It also removes the struct element that was freed from the list.Here's the code:

```
  1 void clean_list(node* node_null,int* nr_elements_ptr,bool free_everything){
  2           node* prev=node_null;
  3           node* curr=node_null;
  4           node* nxt=node_null->next;
  5           int itr= *nr_elements_ptr;
  6           for(int i=0;i<itr;i++){
  7                   curr=nxt;
  8                   if(prev->next!=nxt)
  9                   prev=prev->next;
 10                   if(i!=itr-1)
 11                           nxt=nxt->next;
 12                   if(!(curr->alive) || free_everything){
 13                          if(i!=itr-1)
 14                                  prev->next=nxt;
 15                          else prev->next=NULL;
 16                          free(curr);
 17                          *nr_elements_ptr-=1;
 18                   }
 19           }       
 20   
 21 }
```

My question is that how can I make the function take any type of struct(given it contains an 'alive' field),not just 'node' typedef, so that it can be useful for my other programs. If someone has already a similar question, please excuse my ignorance and point me to the appropriate link.Thankyou.

Comment: What exactly is "any type of struct(given it contains an 'alive' field)"? That's not "any type", that's a very specific type.

Comment: like if I define another struct in another program not necessarily defined as typedef node and pass it to this function

Comment: For future question please don't include line-numbers in your code snippets.

Comment: That's a very odd requirement. The easiest way to go about it is to have a node which in turn contains something like a `void*` to the data.

Comment: This sounds like you want to have some convenience library for memory bookkeeping and such. Consider using something like memory pools from the Apache portable runtime.

Comment: @cheatah, yeah that would be nice, but what would be nicer is if I code some basic easy functions like these myself as I am a newbie and would really appreciate the learning in the process

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* "make the function take any type of struct". Not directly anyway.

There *is* a way to work around the limitation of C not having generics, and that is by using a kind of inheritance.

You create a *base* structure containing only the `alive` field:

```
struct base
{
    int alive;  // Or whatever type is suitable
};
```

Then you can "inherit" this structure. Either by including the structure itself in the other structure:

```
struct child1
{
    struct base base;
    // Other members...
};
```

Or by having the `alive` explicitly as the first member:

```
struct child2
{
    int alive;
    // Other members...
};
```

Note: it's very important that the `base` structure or the `alive` member being the very first member in the structure, otherwise the inheritance won't work.

Now you can pass a pointer to `struct base` as argument, and can type-cast child-structures as the base, and you can access the `alive` member.

---

Simple example using the structures defined above:

```
void function(struct base *base)
{
    printf("alive is %d\n", base->alive);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct child1 c1 = { 1 };
    struct child2 c2 = { 0 };

    // Cast to (pointer to) the common base class
    function((struct base *) &c1);
    function((struct base *) &c2);
}
```

Comment: I don't quite follow how can we cast the child as base and access the alive field???If we typecast the struct to  base then does it get restructured in some way to yield only the no of fields/members contained in struct base(irrespective of datatype)?? is it the reason why the alive and base members needed to be first so that they could still be accessed after typecasting?

Comment: @EL337_H4XX0R There's a rule "common initial sequence" that let us access the initial part of a struct using a pointer to a struct of different type, long as they share the same first member(s).

Comment: @EL337_H4XX0R I'm away now but will add example later.

Comment: "share same member"? is it purpose -wise same or datatype-wise same, like child1 contains a different  datatype of first member than base(i.e 'base' not 'int' )but helps serving same purpose,so...?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no problemo mate

Comment: @Someprogrammer dude, weren't u going to provide some examples??

Comment: @EL337_H4XX0R Patience my young padawan.  Let me have the weekend with sauna and hot-tub and alcohol and all around a great time, and I'll do it as soon as I can.

Comment: @EL337_H4XX0R Added very simple example

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in the case of child 1 , do  we not have to specify something like .base={1} ?? And what about my question about typecasting?? what exactly happens behind the scenes?

Comment: @EL337_H4XX0R You can initialize the structures as shown in my example. And type-casting is basically telling the compiler to pretende that the type of an expression as another type. When doing e.g. `(struct base *) &c1` you tell the compiler to pretend that the type of `&c1` (which is really of the type `struct child2 *`) as the type `struct base *` instead. And since the "common initial sequence" of both the `base` and `child1` structures are the same this will work fine.

Comment: Ok thankyou Someprogrammerdude, you really are "some" programmerJK